# php domdocument check span class

Tags: php, html, domdocument, dom

How can I iterate all  tag and check if class is font18 or font17?

```
 $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->load('file.html');
```

html:

```
    <p><a name="bookmark7"></a><span class="font18" style="font-weight:bold;">Abilitazione</span></p>
<p><span class="font17">I medici devono essere autorizzati dallo Stato a praticare la loro professione. I requisiti per ottenere questa autorizzazione variano a seconda delle diverse Nazioni. I laureati presso Facoltà mediche estere possono ottenere l'autorizzazione a esercitare in Italia se rispondono ai requisiti statali per quanto riguarda il tirocinio e se superano l'esame di Stato. Nell'ambito della CEE si tratta tuttora di una questione da definire nei particolari.</span></p>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean "Check If" As far as I can see, you have elements with one or the other. You want to *check* if each element has one? Or you want an array of elements with one or the other? Or maybe count all the times each class occurs? What do you want, and what have you tried?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The follwing will loop through all `span` tags and you can use this to check the class (if the HTML snippet you provided is indeed the one you are using):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->load('file.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//span');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getAttribute('class');
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/pQuQw1

If the HTML is actually different you can tell me so I can change my snippet. It may also be worthwhile to only select specific elements in the xpath query (e.g. to only select elements with class `font17` or `font18`) .

*Note that I have used DOMXPath because this will give you more flexibility to change the query to select the elements you need depending on your HTML*

If you only want to select elements with class `font17` or `font18` you can change the query to something like:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//span[contains(@class, "font17")]|//span[contains(@class, "font18")]');
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mHo5P7

Answer (score 6):

Your HTML would give error of `Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE0 0x20 0x6D 0x65` if you use `$doc->load("file.html");` here is a simple work around

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("file.html"));

foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $node ) {
    if (preg_match("/^font1[7|8]$/", $node->getAttribute('class'))) {
        echo $node->nodeValue, "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```