# Echo all the paragraphs of a specific class

Tags: php, html, domdocument, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

Is there a way to echo (with PHP) all the paragraphs (of an HTML page) that belong to a specific class ? I've tried something like this but it didn't work (it didn't echo anything)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); //the code I need is contained in the $html variable
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
        if ( $paragraph->getAttribute('class') === 'items') {
            echo $paragraph->nodeValue."<br>";
        }
}
```

Comment: take note that this doesn't match `class="items small-font center"`, just use `strpos` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php domdocument check span class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186148/php-domdocument-check-span-class)

Answer (score 1):

Backing up what Ghost mentions, it is better to use strpos if you have more than one class. Take this as an example.

```
<?php

$html = "<p class='items two small-font'>This is paragraph 1</p> <br> <hr> <p class='items'>This is paragraph 2</p> <br> <hr> <p class='noitem'>This is paragraph 3</p> <br> <hr>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {

    $class = $paragraph->getAttribute('class');

    if ( strpos( $class , 'items') !== false ) {
        echo $paragraph->nodeValue."<br>";
    }

} 

?>
```